# python nltk plots are not showing up

Tags: python, numpy, plot, nltk

I am using Python 2.7.1+ in my Ubuntu 11.04 natty laptop. I installed nltk and all the dependencies to plot graph:

```
   matplotlib==1.1.0

   nltk==2.0b9

   numpy==1.5.1

   scipy==0.8.0
```

However, when I try to plot a graph (as follows), nothing is showing up (no error code as well):

```
   user@user-laptop-ubuntu:~$ python

   Python 2.7.1+ (r271:86832, Apr 11 2011, 18:13:53) 

   [GCC 4.5.2] on linux2

   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

   >>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

   >>> plt.plot(range(10), range(10))

   [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x2770fd0>]

   >>> plt.title("Simple Plot")

   <matplotlib.text.Text object at 0x2607610>

   >>> plt.show()

   >>>
```

or, this code:

```
   >>> from nltk.book import *

   >>> text4.dispersion_plot(["citizens", "democracy"])
```

Funny thing is, I have the same configuration in my desktop Ubuntu 11.04 and the plot is showing up there. I have similar libraries installed in both the computer.

I am totally puzzled now. Any suggestion will be cordially welcomed :-)

Gias

Comment: I also have Python 2.7.1+ and Ubuntu 11.04, and the above Python shell code works fine to produce a plot for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
import matplot.pyplot as plt
from nltk.book import *
text4.dispersion_plot(["citizens", "democracy"])
plt.show()
```

I dont understand your question. But this trick works for me to plot nltk dispersion plot. Explain your question in detail.

Thank You